# Zend Predicate or Predicatset

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I want to add parenthesis my request but I do not know how. Can you help me ?
My SQL query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_my_asn_header 
WHERE username = 'toto' 
  AND (shipment_number LIKE '20151106052811' OR 
       shipment_number LIKE '20151110053250' OR 
       shipment_number LIKE '20151116054359') 
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

My fonction :

```
public function searchSitesDeliveries($username, Search $search)
{
     $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
     array(new Predicate\Expression('username = ?', $username)),Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_AND);

    if (!empty($search->get_shipment_number()))
    {
      $valeur = $search->get_shipment_number();
      if(is_array($valeur)) 
      {
          $valeur = array_unique($valeur);
          foreach ($valeur as $key => $value) 
          {
              if($key == 0)
              {
                $predicate_set->andPredicate(new Predicate\Expression('shipment_number IN', '%'.$value.'%'));
                $predicate_set->nest();
                $bool = true;
              }
              else
              {
                  $predicate_set->orPredicate(new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '%'.$value.'%'));     
              }
           }
           if($bool == true)   
           {
               $predicate_set->unnest();                             
           }
        }
        else {
           $predicate_set->andPredicate(new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '%'.$valeur.'%'));
        }
    }

    $select->where($predicate_set);
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

The $predicate_set->nest; brings back to me a next error :

```
`Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::nest()`
```

Outside , at the beginning of the file , I :

namespace Front\Model;

```
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

use Zend\Db;
use Zend\Db\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
```

use Front\Model\MAH;

What is the problem ?

Thank you

I have write a test:

```
public function searchSitesDeliveries($username, Search $search)
{
        if (!empty($search->get_shipment_number()))
        {
            $valeur = $search->get_shipment_number();
            if(is_array($valeur))
            {
                $toto = array();
                $valeur = array_unique($valeur);
                $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select(); 
                $titi = "$" ;
                $compteur = 0;
                foreach ($valeur as $key => $value) 
                {                    
                    $toto[$compteur] = $value;
                    $compteur = $compteur + 1;
                }
                for ($i=0; $i < ($compteur); $i++) { 
                    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($toto[$i]);
                    if($i== 0 || $i == $compteur )
                    {
                        $titi = $titi . "select->where->equalTo('user_name', '".$username."')->next->like('shipment_number','".$toto[$i]."')";    
                    }
                    else
                    {                     
                        $titi = $titi . "->or->like('shipment_number','".$toto[$i]."')->unnest;";
                    }
                }   
                \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($titi);             
                $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith(eval($titi));
            }
        }
        return $resultSet;
}
```

But :

```
string(173) "$select->where->equalTo('user_name', 'toto')->next->like('shipment_number','20151125056269')->or->like('shipment_number','20151014048501')->unnest;"
```

and :

```
Message error : Not nested
```

Comment: You probably have an error in your code as $predicate_set is not defined. But if you look at the classes of zend-db, the Predicate class extends  PredicateSet and defines methods nest() and unnest().

Comment: You can fix as newage says. Personally, instead of using PredicateSet class I use the class Predicate (or Where, it's the same).

Comment: You have a exemple with a predicat class.

Comment: And my problem is dynamic, where soluction is dynamic. Since I have a table of data so I do not know the size of its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dynamic solution:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

public function searchSitesDeliveries($username, Search $search)
{
    if (!empty($search->get_shipment_number()))
    {
        $valeur = $search->get_shipment_number();
        if(is_array($valeur))
        {
            $result = array();
            $valeur = array_unique($valeur);
            $where = new Where();
            $where->equalTo('username', $username);
            if (!empty($valeur) {
                  $where->nest();
                  $or = false;
                foreach ($valeur as $value) 
                {   
                      if ($or) $where->or;
                    $where->like('shipment_number', $value)
                    $or = true;
                }
                $where->unnest();
            }
            $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();             
            $select->where($where);
            $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
            return $resultSet;
        }
        // error processing ... when $valeur isn't an array
    }
    // error processing ... when get_shipment_number is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example more simplier

```
$select->where->equalTo('user_name', $userName)
   ->nest()
       ->like('shipment_number', '20151106052811')
       ->or
       ->like('shipment_number', '20151110053250')
       ->or
       ->like('shipment_number', '20151116054359')
   ->unnest()
```

If you want use `Predicate`'s

```
$predicate = new Predicate\PredicateSet(
    [
        new Predicate\Operator('user_name', Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO, $userName),
        new Predicate\PredicateSet(
            [
                new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '20151106052811'),
                new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '20151110053250'),
                new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '20151116054359'),
            ],
            Predicate\Predicate::COMBINED_BY_OR
    ],
    Predicate\Predicate::COMBINED_BY_AND
);
$select->where->addPredicate($predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the response of @newage is the good one but maybe you can use IN SQL Statement like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_my_asn_header 
WHERE username = 'toto'
  AND shipment_number IN ('20151106052811', '20151110053250', '20151116054359')      
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

With Zend\Db you can use

```
new Predicate\In('shipment_number',array('20151106052811', '20151110053250', '20151116054359'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I 'm doing this soluction , it works, but I do not like my code because it is static , if someone has a tip to make it dynamic I'm interested.

```
public function searchSitesDeliveries($username, Search $search)
{
    if (!empty($search->get_shipment_number()))
    {
        $valeur = $search->get_shipment_number();
        if(is_array($valeur))
        {
            $result = array();
            $valeur = array_unique($valeur);
            $compteur = 0;
            foreach ($valeur as $key => $value) 
            {   
                $compteur = $compteur + 1;                             
                $result[$compteur] = $value;
            }
            $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select(); 
            switch($compteur)
            {
                case '1':
                    $predicate_set = new Predicate\PredicateSet(array(new Predicate\Expression('username = ?', $username)), Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_AND);
                    $predicate_set->andPredicate(new Predicate\Like('shipment_number', '%'.$valeur.'%')); 
                    $select->where($predicate_set);
                break;
                case '2':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                   ->nest()
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '3':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                          ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '4':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '5':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                        ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[5].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '6':
                 $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                        ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[5].'')
                       ->or
                       ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[6].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '7':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[5].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[6].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[7].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '8':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[5].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[6].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[7].'')                            
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[8].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
                case '9':
                    $select->where->equalTo('username', $username)
                    ->nest()
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[1].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[2].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[3].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[4].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[5].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[6].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[7].'')                            
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[8].'')
                        ->or
                        ->like('shipment_number', ''.$result[9].'')
                   ->unnest();
                break;
            }
            $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        }

    }
    return $resultSet;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($valeur)) {
    $nest = false;
    $valeur = array_unique($valeur);

    /* Select */
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $where = $select->where('user_name', $userName);

    /* Open nest if $valuer has more 1 values */
    if ($nest === false && count($valuer) > 1) {
        $nest = true;
        $where = $where->nest();
    }

    /* Add like and or to where */
    while (count($valuer) > 0) {
        $value = array_shift($valuer);
        $where = $where->like('shipment_number', $value);
        if (count($valuer) > 0) {
            $where = $where->or;
        }
    }

    /* Close nest */
    if ($nest === true && empty($valuer)) {
        $where->unnest();
    }
}
```